# Ef core 2.1 unable to de-serialize SQL Geography

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am using .Net core 2 and EF core 2.1 to query a DB field that has a type of Geography.
It is throwing an error, and seems to not be able to deserialize the field - Ideally I would like to get the lat/long value out.
What am I missing?

The below code works to return all the other fields (mostly string / varChar)
but fails with the Geography. 
Also, when I use LinqPad, I am able to query the field and get a response, so I think it may be related to the EFCore 2.1.

```
var tu = _tuContext.tuLocation
                    .Where(d => d.OrgID == 1)
                    .Select(v => new
                    {
                        e = v.TuLocationPoint
                    });
```

I have also tried:

```
var tu = _tuContext.tuLocation
                        .Where(d => d.OrgID == 1)
                        .Select(v => new
                        {
                            e = v.TuLocationPoint.Latitude
                        });
```

Comment: @Dasha EF-Core 2.1 is not out yet on nuget, are you using the unofficial DotNet Version or did you really mean 2.01

Comment: Johnny, you are correct - I mean 2.0.1.

Comment: As a work around, I have created two computed columns in the database - one for Lat and one for Long.

Comment: You need to provide more code, Where is your materialization? ToList

Comment: materialization is immaterial, but yes .ToList()

Comment: There is no to list in what you’ve provided show the whole code